# Need to remove an image/link from my website

Tags: javascript, image, hyperlink, web-hosting

I have been tasked with updating a website. The website is hosted by dexone and they are kind enough (sarcasm) to place an ad at the bottom of all my pages linking back to their sales and services page. The link and image are not editable by me (it uses cm4all as the content manager) and when the site is published they are adding some code to the footer to display their image/link. The image/link code is:

```
<a style="float:right;" href="http://www.dexone.com/solutions/websites" target="_blank"><img src="http://cm4allfooters.websiteexperts.com/dex/dex.jpg" alt="Dex  website Solutions" title="Dex Website Solutions" height="39" width="180"></a>
```

I am wondering if using javascript this could be "removed". CSS maybe but I do not see a reference to anything other than img and if I change img to hidden it removes all images on the site and not just this image. 
Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. On a side note I am not a java guy I work in php mostly so if you want to give me an example it will need to be complete or I will screw it up I am sure.
Thanks all!

Comment: before you proceed with this, you should look at whatever contract/agreement you made with them for hosting, to verify that this isn't against their ToS. if you do this and they detect it, they may immediately drop you. this might just be one of those fine print things that they require you to deal with as a part of hosting with them.

Comment: [tag:java] and [tag:javascript] are not the same thing; I'm *assuming* that you *mean* JavaScript?

Comment: I already talked to the host. They will not drop us and it is not against the terms and conditions. They claim they are unable to do it as it is a feature for all their hosted sites. They will let me remove it (I already removed the java script they used to track the users following that link but can not seem to get rid of the image/link. Thanks for thinking about the drawbacks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with 'Java' but this would probably work in your CSS:

```
a[href*='//www.dexone.com'] { display: none; }
```

Yes! Highly recommend you follow Mike Cs advice before implementing this solution.

Comment: Will give it a try and let you know. I had not seen css done quite the way you are showing but.....

Comment: To clarify, that selector says give me all `a` tags with an `href` attribute that contains the string '//www.dexone.com'. Background: http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/

Comment: @Kevin YOU ROCK!!! and I got to learn something new about css!!! Thank you that has been bugging me all day!!!! If I had any reputation I would give you an up arrow.

Comment: Thanks, Sean. You CAN mark the answer as accepted (which is even better than an upvote). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

here is how to do it via straight up javascript:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i=0; i<elems.length; ++i) {
    if (elems[i].href == "http://www.dexone.com/solutions/websites") {
        elems[i].parentNode.removeChild(elems[i]);
    }
}
```

and using jQuery:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    if (this.href == "http://www.dexone.com/solutions/websites") {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```